# Mettre un logiciel en production

Tags: vocabulaire

Bonjour tout le monde,

Je suis en train d'écrire un ticket pour un logiciel, et je cherche à traduire en Anglais "Mettre en production un logiciel".
J'ai pensé à "deploy in production", mais je ne suis pas sûr de moi.

Merci d'avance pour votre temps.

Comment: Pour une traduction vers l'anglais il faut poser ta question sur 
English Language Learners : http://ell.stackexchange.com/            French Language & Usage is not a text translation or proofreading service. Questions about translation from French to another language and translations and proofreading of whole texts are off-topic.

Comment: @Laure Ma réponse précédait de quelques secondes ce commentaire ; pourquoi refuser une aide quand on peut dépanner instantanément ? Mais bien d'accord pour refuser ceux qui font relire des textes entiers - il existe des sites de correcteurs d'épreuves.

Comment: @MarkThorin Un grand merci pour votre réponse; j'avais trouvé des outils et des dictionnaires, mais aucun ne présentait d'entrée pour les termes d'environnement de production informatique. Je saurai pour l'avenir. Bonne fin de journée.

Comment: Cela était bien facile pour moi, bilingue et au fait de l'informatique ; si je peux vous aider, très ponctuellement, à l'avenir, vous avez mon adresse dans mon profil, et ne soulèverez aucune objection de Stack Exchange.

Comment: @MarkThorin Votre adresse est confidentielle, seuls les employés de Stack Exchange (et peut-être les modérateurs des sites où vous avez un profil) y ont accès.

Comment: « pourquoi refuser une aide quand on peut dépanner instantanément », c'est à nouveau plus une question pour meta, ça m'arrive de répondre en commentaire et de voter pour fermer le sujet.  L'aspect principal pour moi est que les participants au site n'ont pas la compétence pour juger la qualité des réponses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To instal" ou "to install", tout simplement. "To deploy resource(s)" est correct.